# Programmatically start UserControlTestContainer.exe

Tags: c#

I implemented a C# user control and succesfully tested it with the UserControlTestContainer.exe by manually interacting with it. Now I would like to programmatically, instead of manually, feed data into the control, through my unit tests and then automatically display the control filled with that data. I guess I need to create an instance of the control, fill it up and then programatically start the container with the control as parameter, don't I? How do I succeed displaying my filled control? The solution doesn't have to involve the above mentioned container of course, any other suggestion to get the work done would be very appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to display the control if you're running a unit test? Wouldn't it cut it to prepare the control and directly invoking a click method or whatever?

Comment: The purpose of this particular test is making sure that that big amounts of data feeded into the control is correctly and clearly displayed on some diagramm. It's more like a visual test.

Answer (score 1):

I just created an other "Unit Test" project doing all UserControlTestContainer work. UserControlTestContainer is started through the external application option on the project's properties.

Comment: don't forget to accept the answer, even when you're the one answering it.